# Convert array of hashes to hashes without array and overwrite

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I set the hash variable to an array of hashes:

`[12] pry (main)> hash = {: sku => "1234",: name => "Test"}, {: sku => "5678",: name => "Test2"}`
`=> [{: sku => "1234",: name => "Test"}, {: sku => "5678",: name => "Test2"}]`

But when using data in a loop, I get the "TypeError: can't cast Hash" error.

Question: how to convert array of hashes to hashes without array and overwrite?

To make the hash variable match the following:
`{: sku => "1234",: name => "Test"}, {: sku => "5678",: name => "Test2"}`

Comment: How are you looping? I think the answer to your issue is to allow you to loop through each hash in the array, no?

Comment: @benjessop 
Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: `array_of_hashes.map { |inner_hash| inner_hash.each { |k, v|  #do stuff } }`

Comment: Your "desired hash" is not valid due to the white space in between `:` and the rest. Even if it was "valid" the desire would result in an `Array`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert an array of hashes to hashes'? An array has a sequence of individual elements, but a hash must have a distinct Key and a Value for each element. So what does this conversion look like to you, and why is it necessary/how will it solve your problem? If you're looking to convert each hash object to an array, you can use `array.map do |o| o.to_a end` (but that seems odd). What are you doing with the elements you're iterating over to get that error? This sounds more like an issue with what you're trying to do *to* hash elements while you're iterating over the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have putted an extra space in between `key` and `value` i.e. `: sku`, I believe its a typo mistake. You can parse the data in the following manner.

```
 array_of_hashes = [{:sku=>"1234", :name=>"Test"}, {:sku=>"5678", :name=>"Test2"}]
 array_of_hashes.each do |hash|
   puts "sku = #{hash[:sku]} , name = #{hash[:name]}"
   # Do your stuff
 end
```